# Relationship between props and data (vue)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In

https://codesandbox.io/s/v9pp6

the `ChromePage` component passes a prop to `InventorySectionC`:

```
<inventory-section-component :itemSectionProps="getItemSection">
</inventory-section-component>
```

`InventorySectionC`:

```
<template>
  <div class="inventory-section-component">
    <draggable v-model="itemSectionProps.itemSectionCategory">
      <transition-group>
        <div
          v-for="category in itemSectionProps.itemSectionCategory"
          :key="category.itemSectionCategoryId"
        >
          <!-- <p>{{ category.itemSectionCategoryName }}</p>  -->
          <inventory-section-group-component :itemSectionGroupData="category">
          </inventory-section-group-component>
        </div>
      </transition-group>
    </draggable>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import InventorySectionGroupComponent from "./InventorySectionGroupC";
import draggable from "vuedraggable";

export default {
  name: "InventorySectionComponent",
  components: {
    InventorySectionGroupComponent,
    draggable,
    // GridLayout: VueGridLayout.GridLayout,
    // GridItem: VueGridLayout.GridItem,
  },
  props: {
    itemSectionProps: {
      type: Object,
    },
  },
  data() {
    let itemSectionData = itemSectionProps;
    return {
      itemSectionData
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

gives a warning at line:

```
<draggable v-model="itemSectionProps.itemSectionCategory">
```

:

```
Unexpected mutation of "itemSectionProps" prop. (vue/no-mutating-props)eslint
```

Why (how?) is `itemSectionProps` mutable?

Can a binding be created between `props` and `data` (all draggable samples use a data object:

https://sortablejs.github.io/Vue.Draggable/#/nested-example
https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable/blob/master/example/components/nested-example.vue
)?

The idea is to have auto updating, nested, draggable components.

The code as is "works" but there are warnings/errs:

`data()` can't seem to see `props`:

[image]

And one more thing, which comes "first"? `Data` or `props`? can't seem to figure it out from the docs:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html

Setting the props to a predefined value:

```
  props: {
     itemSectionProps: {
       type: Object,
       default: { itemSectionCategory: '' }
      },
   },
```

gives:

```
Type of the default value for 'itemSectionProps' prop must be a function. (vue/require-valid-default-prop).
```

[image]

I'm not sure why vue expects props to return a function.

After adding a `default()` onto props, props are empty when passed on to components:

https://codesandbox.io/s/sjm0x

Comment: Props can't be mutated. Use data() variables in v-model for draggable. Try accessing props in data by `this.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Draggable vue components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67967262/draggable-vue-components)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(this grew too long for a comment, but probably already answers what you need)*

**itemSectionProps:**

Your props are defined as:

```js
  props: {
    itemSectionProps: {
      type: Object,
    },
  },
```

You reference a prop of that object in your template

```html
<draggable v-model="itemSectionProps.itemSectionCategory">
```

Vue cannot assume `itemSectionProps.itemSectionCategory` will exist in the future.
You should give it a default (see [Vue docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-props.html#prop-validation)) to create the expected values in that object.

```js
  props: {
    itemSectionProps: {
      type: Object,
      default() {
        return { itemSectionCategory: '' };
      }
    },
  },
```

Do this for all the props you use on itemSectionProps.

**data() can't seem to see props:**

You can write `this.itemSectionProps` instead of only `itemSectionProps`.
But `itemSectionProps` is already defined in `props`. You can just remove `itemSectionProps` from `data`.

If you need to change that value, use a copy and promote changes with [this.$emit](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/emits-option.html#_3-x-behavior).

Comment: Setting the default doesn't seem to work (edits).

Comment: Ah thanks for the edit. The error message is saying `default` needs to be a function. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Added the default but props get lost on the way(edit).

Comment: Okay but the problem seems to be somewhere else now. You should address all the console errors first one by one. For example `TypeError: Cannot read property 'itemSection' of null` is an unrelated error and should be addressed first.  
I currently don't have the time to debug all of it for you.

Comment: Yes, that error comes from not having a default section selected on first load/refresh but moving through the section looks alright in the console (no errs/ws). Opened a separate q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67983345/props-not-being-saved-to-a-local-state-in-vue-components?noredirect=1#comment120160448_67983345

Comment: (cont'd) Scoping to curr object `this.itemSectionData` regardless of whether the object is locally defined or the prop (the prop gives mutation warning) the result is the same.

Comment: added default to props `return { itemSectionCategory: {} };` but I'm not sure since the default is nested in a parent object the prop does it mean that when the prop is fetched by the component, even if it is null/empty it will be instantiated to an object with that default? In this case `itemSectionProps` should always be at least empty (not null) with a  subfield `itemSectionProps`, right?

Comment: Yes the default should be an object with a `itemSectionCategory` property, which is an empty object. I suggest you install the Vue Devtools browser extension where you can see it directly, that can help a lot. I would still address all console errors first if I were you.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably calling the props without using `this.` on your data method.

You can as well define your variable `itemSectionData` as below:

```
    data(){ 
       return {
           itemSectionData: Object.assign({}, this.itemSectionProps)
        }
    }
```

**Object.assign()**
The `Object.assign()` method copies all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It returns the target object. See more details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Then use the newly defined variable `itemSectionData` within your component. Like:

```
<draggable v-model="itemSectionData.itemSectionCategory">
```

If you want to update the prop's values, simply emit an event from your child component and capture it on the parent as below:

```
    methods:{
     updatePropValues(){
        this.$emit('updateProp', this.yourNewValues);
      }
    }
```

On the parent component handle the event as:

```
<inventory-section-component @updateProp="setNewValues" :itemSectionProps="getItemSection">
  </inventory-section-component>

methods:{
  setNewValues(newValues){
     this.itemSections = newValues;
   }
}
```

Check it out in action [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-firefly-i3iiv?file=/src/components/InventorySectionC.vue)

Comment: Props are not being passed in the sandbox