# Props not being saved to a local state in vue components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-props

([follow-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67968062/relationship-between-props-and-data-vue/67968452?noredirect=1#comment120158469_67968452)).

In

https://codesandbox.io/s/sjm0x

props are intended to be saved to a local object (for later use) and rendered from there. It should look/behave like:

https://codesandbox.io/s/v9pp6

("Books" and "Movies" are both draggable).

First working case:

```
<template>
  <div class="inventory-section-component">
    <draggable v-model="itemSectionProps.itemSectionCategory">
      <transition-group>
        <div
          v-for="category in itemSectionProps.itemSectionCategory"
          :key="category.itemSectionCategoryId"
        >
          <!-- <p>{{ category.itemSectionCategoryName }}</p>  -->
          <inventory-section-group-component :itemSectionGroupData="category">
          </inventory-section-group-component>
        </div>
      </transition-group>
    </draggable>
  </div>
</template>
```

produces:

[image]

but uses props directly and does not take into account mutations:

[image]

The second example:

```
<template> 
  <div class="inventory-section-component">
    <draggable v-model="this.itemSectionData.itemSectionCategory">
      <transition-group>
        <div
          v-for="category in this.itemSectionData.itemSectionCategory"
          :key="category.itemSectionCategoryId"
        >
          <inventory-section-group-component :itemSectionGroupProps="category">
          </inventory-section-group-component>
        </div>
      </transition-group>
    </draggable>
  </div>
</template>
```

saves props to a local object `itemSectionData` but the output no longer gets rendered:

[image]

Comment: please share the relevant and explain where's the issue exactly, keep also the reproduction links

Comment: I didn't vote to close the question, I don't close the user's question with a good reputation since I know that he will edit it when it's needed

Comment: In the second example, do you need `this.` in `v-for="category in this.itemSectionData.itemSectionCategory`?

Comment: It's for "good measure"; the output/behavior is the same regardless

Answer (score 0):

First define `itemSectionData` as an empty object in your data method.

```
    data() {
      return {
        itemSectionData: {}
    };
  }
```

Then define a watcher for the prop `itemSectionProps` being passed to the component and assign it's values to the newly defined variable `itemSectionData` like such:

```
    watch: {
    itemSectionProps: {
      handler() {
        this.itemSectionData = this.itemSectionProps;
      }
    }
  }
```

You can then use the new variable within the component

Check this out https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-sun-smexc?file=/src/components/InventorySectionC.vue:1117-1242